# Correct item is not selected in Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am using this [Tutorial](http://rudisss.blogspot.in/2012/10/listview-with-radio-buttons-and.html) for Creating a custom listview with radio button. In this tutorial when we click the item in the list then color of item change.

This is happening when i am testing this code above 4.0 but below 4.0 it is not workin properly I am  not understand why????

Class Blog.java

```
public class Blog extends Activity {


 ListView listView;

ArrayList< String>arrayList; // list of the strings that should appear in ListView
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter; // a middle man to bind ListView and array list 


  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.custom);

      listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstDemo);


      // LIST OF STRINGS / DATA THAT SHOULD APPEAR IN LISTVIEW HERE WE HAVE HARD CODED     IT WE CAN TAKE THIS INPUT FROM USER AS WELL

      arrayList = new ArrayList();
      arrayList.add("India");
      arrayList.add("USA");
      arrayList.add("England");
      arrayList.add("Singapur");
      arrayList.add("China");
      arrayList.add("Canada");
      arrayList.add("Srilanka");
      arrayList.add("SouthAfrica");




       arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,arrayList);
       listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    //  LETS HIGHLIGHT SELECTED ITEMS

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View view, int position,
 long itemId) {


/*  
 *  when we click on item on list view we can get it catch item here.
 * so view is the item clicked in list view and position is the position 
 * of that item in list view which was clicked.
 * 
 * Now that we know which item is click we can easily change the color
 * of text but when we click on next item we we have to deselect the old 
 * selected item means recolor it back to default , and then hight the 
 * new selected item by coloring it .
 * 
 * So here's the code of doing it.
 * 
 * 
 * */


CheckedTextView textView = (CheckedTextView) view;
for (int i = 0; i < listView.getCount(); i++) {
 textView= (CheckedTextView) listView.getChildAt(i);
 if (textView != null) {
  textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
 }

}
listView.invalidate();
textView = (CheckedTextView) view;
if (textView != null) {
 textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
}

   }
});   

    }
}
```

My xml View

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lstDemo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice">

</ListView>
```

Comment: May I knw why this is dowgrade my question

Comment: Please provide more information and code to support....

Comment: As you are not specified with your question. This question sense nothing. Put what U did and what U need

Comment: @AndroidHacker Now you help me

Comment: So U are not able to create list view?

Comment: this code creating listview and work properly but when click on any item then it it change the color of another item not which i selected. It will happen in 2.2 but this code is running propely in 4.0 and above. you can run this code and check it. It is complete code

Comment: For me plz run my code then you can realize my problem but in android below 4.0 then above 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Show us your adapter code as well and try not to change an item of list view from setOnItemClickListener instead change your data and notify adapter to refresh the view.

Set this as background to your list item :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/white" />
    <item android:color="@color/black" />
</selector>
```

Comment: my problem is that code work fine in 4.0 and above but not in below 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Define your variables like this

```
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListView lv;
    private ArrayList<GoModelAll> m_ArrayList = null;
    GoArrayAdapter gaa;
```

Define your AsyncTask like this

```
new GoAsyncTask().execute();
```

Your AsyncTask class Code like this

```
class GoAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

        /*pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();*/
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        sal = new StaticApiList();
        myUrl = StaticApiList.go_api;
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(myUrl);

        try {
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            System.out.println("httpResponse");

            InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    inputStreamReader);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String bufferedStrChunk = null;
            while ((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
            }
            jsonString = stringBuilder.toString();
            Log.i("talk_all_json", jsonString);
            return stringBuilder.toString();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
            System.out.println("Exception generates caz of httpResponse :"
                    + cpe);
            cpe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out
                    .println("Second exception generates caz of httpResponse :"
                            + ioe);
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        vivek = true;
        try{
            m_ArrayList = new ArrayList<GoModelAll>(); 
            if (jsonString.length() > 0) {
                   JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
                        dh.open();
                        for(int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            description = jObject.getString("description");
                            excert = jObject.getString("excert");
                            thumsrc = jObject.getString("thumsrc");
                            title = jObject.getString("title");
                            postid = jObject.getInt("postid");
                            Log.d("talklog", "Title -> " + title + " , thumsrc -> " + thumsrc
                                    + " , excert -> " + excert + " , description -> " + description);
                            Log.d("talklog", "============================= end of " + i + " ===============================");

                            gma = new GoModelAll();
                            gma.description = description;
                            gma.excert = excert;
                            gma.thumsrc = thumsrc;
                            gma.title = title;
                            gma.postid = postid;
                            Cursor cursor = dh.getSeenStatus(gma.postid);
                            if(cursor.getCount()>0)
                            {
                                cursor.moveToFirst();
                                if(cursor.getInt(0) == 0)
                                {
                                    gma.isSeen = false;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    gma.isSeen = true;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                            cv.put(DbHandler.KEY_ID, postid);
                            cv.put(DbHandler.KEY_VALUE, 0);
                            dh.addData(DbHandler.TABLE_SEEN, cv);
                            }
                            m_ArrayList.add(gma);
                        }
                        dh.close();
            }

            gaa = new GoArrayAdapter(getActivity(), m_ArrayList);
            lv = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.go_list);
            lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
            lv.setAdapter(gaa);

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dh.open();
                    dh.updateSeenStatus(m_ArrayList.get(arg2).postid, 1);
                    m_ArrayList.get(arg2).isSeen = true;
                    dh.close();
                    GoDetail fragment = new GoDetail();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                    bundle.putString("title", m_ArrayList.get(arg2).title);
                    bundle.putString("excert", m_ArrayList.get(arg2).excert);
                    bundle.putString("description", m_ArrayList.get(arg2).description);
                    bundle.putString("thumsrc", m_ArrayList.get(arg2).thumsrc);
                    bundle.putString("header_title", "Go");
                    //bundle.putInt("postid", m_ArrayList.get(arg2).postid);

                    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    ((BaseContainerFragment)getParentFragment()).replaceFragment(fragment, true);
                }
            });

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //pDialog.dismiss();
        pd.dismiss();
    }

}
```

Your Adapter class

```
public class GoArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GoModelAll> {
    private final Context context;
    ImageLoader imgLoader;
    private final ArrayList<GoModelAll> values;
    DataHelper dh;
    public GoArrayAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<GoModelAll> values) {
        super(context, R.layout.go_row, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
        imgLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
        dh = new DataHelper(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.go_row, parent, false);

        /**  Get view over here.. */
        GoModelAll asm = values.get(position);
        TextView title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.go_tv);
        ImageView business_logo = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.go_image);
        ImageView go_red = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.go_red);
        if(asm.isSeen)
        {
            go_red.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        /**Set view over here..*/

        title.setText(asm.title);

         // Loader image - will be shown before loading image
        int loader = R.drawable.image_not_available;
        String image_url = asm.thumsrc;
        imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, loader, business_logo);

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

At last your Model class

```
public class GoModelAll {

    public String description = "";
    public String excert = "";
    public String thumsrc = "";
    public String title = "";
    public int postid = 0;
    public boolean isSeen = false;

}
```