# ListViewActivity with Custom Adapter doesn' t work

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, baseadapter

Dear Stackoverflow Comunitiy,

I'd like to have a ListView getting filled by an BackgroundTask.
This is my actual Code

HomeActivity:

```
package com.example.instaemgnew;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.example.instaemgnew.classes.Beitrag;
import com.example.instaemgnew.classes.beitragLoader;
import com.example.instaemgnew.classes.listViewHomeActivitiyAdapter;

public class HomeActivity extends ListActivity {
    listViewHomeActivitiyAdapter adapter;
     ArrayList<Beitrag> beitraege = new ArrayList<Beitrag>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);


        adapter = new listViewHomeActivitiyAdapter(this, beitraege);
         setListAdapter(adapter);
         Log.e("TestPoint 1", "Adapter Set");

        new beitragLoader(this).execute();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void addToListView(Beitrag toAddBeitrag){
        beitraege.add(toAddBeitrag);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }




}
```

BackgroundTask:

```
package com.example.instaemgnew.classes;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.example.instaemgnew.HomeActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class beitragLoader extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    //Array List für die Beiträge
    ArrayList<Beitrag> beitraege;

    //User Daten
    /*mail = userManager.getMail();
    grade = String.valueOf(userManager.getGrade());
    school = userManager.getSchool();*/
    String mail = "simon-frey@gmx.de";
    String grade = String.valueOf(334);
    String school = "EMG";

    //JSONParser
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    //ArrayList mit Beitrag Objekten
    ArrayList<Beitrag> beitraegeList;

    // Onlinedaten
    private static final String SERVER_URL = "http://yooui.de/InstaEMGTest/";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "8615daf406f7e2b313494f0240";

    //Context
    private final HomeActivity homeActivity;

    //Konstruktor
    public beitragLoader(HomeActivity homeActivity){
        this.homeActivity = homeActivity;
         Log.e("TestPoint 2", "Created beitragLoader");

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //TODO: Test for InternetConnection
         Log.e("TestPoint 3", "PreExectute");

    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        beitraegeList = new ArrayList<Beitrag>();
        String SQLUrl = SERVER_URL + "testBeiträgeAbrufen.php";
        String token = getMD5Hash("password" + "data");

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", token));
        //TODO: params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("page", skipBeitraege))    
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grade", grade));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("school", school));

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(SQLUrl, "GET", params);


        if (json == null) {
            // Server offline

        }

         Log.e("TestPoint 3,5", "FetchedJSON");


        try {
            JSONArray beitraege = json.getJSONArray("beitraege");


             // looping through All Products
            for (int i = 0; i < beitraege.length(); i++) {
                Beitrag tempBeitrag = null;

                 Log.e("TestPoint 3,6", "StartLoop");

                JSONObject c = beitraege.getJSONObject(i);

                //HDImagesURLList ArrayList
                ArrayList<String> HDImagesURLList = new ArrayList<String>();

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString("ID");
                String url = c.getString("url");
                String titel = c.getString("titel");
                String tags = c.getString("tags");
                String onlineDate = c.getString("onlineDate");

                 Log.e("TestPoint 3,7", "Stored JSON Items");


                //Fetching previewImage
                try {
                     Log.e("TestPoint 3,8", "TryImageDownload");

                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
                String fileName = "InstaEMG" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())+".jpg";

                 Log.e("imageUri", url);
                 Log.e("fileName", fileName);


                FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),fileName));

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bufferLength = 0;
                while ((bufferLength = in.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                      fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                      Log.e("File Output", String.valueOf(bufferLength));
                }


               //Fill HDImagesURLList
               //TODO


                // creating newBeitrag
               tempBeitrag = new Beitrag(Integer.parseInt(id), titel, onlineDate,  fileName, HDImagesURLList);




                // adding Beitrag to ArrayList
                beitraegeList.add(tempBeitrag);

             Log.e("TestPoint 4", "NewBeitragSet");

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                     Log.e("Exceptrion", "URL Exception");

                } catch (IOException e) {
                     Log.e("Exceptrion", "IO Exception");

                }
                homeActivity.addToListView(tempBeitrag);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        return null;       
    }

    /**
     * After completing background Safe to MainActivity
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute() {
         Log.e("TestPoint 5", "PostExecutre");

        // homeActivity.updateListView(beitraegeList);

    }

    /**
     * Methode zum Errechnen eines MD5Hashs
     * 
     * @param string
     *            String welcher kodiert werden soll
     * @return MD5 Hash des Strings, bei Fehler der ursprüngliche String.
     */
    private String getMD5Hash(String string) {
        try {
            MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            md5.update(string.getBytes());
            byte[] result = md5.digest();

            StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                if ((0xff & result[i]) < 0x10) {
                    hexString.append("0" + Integer.toHexString((0xFF & result[i])));
                } else {
                    hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & result[i]));
                }
            }
            string = hexString.toString();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        return string;
    };

}
```

and the BaseAdapter:

```
package com.example.instaemgnew.classes;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.example.instaemgnew.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

      public class listViewHomeActivitiyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
          private final Context context;
          private ArrayList<Beitrag> beitraege;
          private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public listViewHomeActivitiyAdapter(Context context,  ArrayList<Beitrag> beitraege) {

          super();
          this.beitraege = beitraege;
          this.context = context;
          this.layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        }


        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Allgemeien Layout Vorgaben  
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
              .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_beitrag_row_layout, parent, false);

          if (convertView == null) {
              convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_beitrag_row_layout, null);
          }

          //getViews
          TextView titelView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.beitragTitel);
          ImageView beitragImageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.beitragImg);
          /*
           * TODO: Tags anzeigen und suchen lassen (Wunschfunktion)
           * TextView tagsView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.beitragTags);
           */



          //setTitel From Object
          titelView.setText(beitraege.get(position).getTitel());

          //setPreviewImage From Object
          beitragImageView.setImageBitmap(beitraege.get(position).getPreviewImage());
          //setOnClickListener on PreviewImage for PopOutGallery
          beitragImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //TODO: PopOut Gallery
            }
          });   

          return rowView;
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return beitraege.size();
        }


        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return beitraege.get(position);
        }


        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        } 




      }
```

In my opinion the Bug have to be in the BaseAdapter, but I don't know where it could be.

Sincerly and thankful,

Simon

Comment: what is that doesn't work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20418253/correct-item-is-not-selected-in-listview check this link for answer

Comment: your `beitraege` value only populates after `AsyncTask` completion so try to set your adapter `onPostExecute()`. You can not directly access your activity's listview from asynctask so try to create interface as a asynctask callback or else write to asynctask within activity class

Comment: Are you getting any UIThread exception ? Since you trying to access the UI from doInbackground

Comment: No, it's an Android Runtime Exception

Comment: I'm not trying to directly access the ListView, this is handeld by th public method 'addToListView()'

Comment: @yooui there are few problems in getview of adapter also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fill listView in doInBackground you need to use Handler, or runOnUiThread, because this is not UI thread.

```
homeActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
{ 
  public void run()
  { 
     homeActivity.addToListView(tempBeitrag); 
}});
```

Comment: Can't this be done with the existing 'addToListView()' method ?

Comment: runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run(){
                    homeActivity.addToListView(tempBeitrag);
                }
            });

Comment: Thank you very much, with this little peace of code it works. Is there any Website explaining this issue, because I'd like to understand why it have to be this way.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Answer (score 0):

```
adapter = new listViewHomeActivitiyAdapter(this, beitraege);
```

`beitraege` is not populated with any data.

Edit:

Instead of calling this from `doInbackground`. Use a Interface as a call back to the activity and then populate listview.

```
 public void addToListView(Beitrag toAddBeitrag){
        beitraege.add(toAddBeitrag);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

[How do I return a boolean from AsyncTask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752073/how-do-i-return-a-boolean-from-asynctask)

Instead of boolen value its arraylist in your case.

Then use the below and set the adapter your listview

```
adapter = new listViewHomeActivitiyAdapter(this, beitraege);
```